# How can I handle text before uploading on the page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to do some processes with text (add some html tags around some symbols) before page is uploaded. How can I do this with hooks in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [wp_insert_post_data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter, this filter is used before the post is saved in the DB.

```
function uts_filter_before_save( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Do whatever you want with $data then
    return $data;

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'uts_filter_before_save' );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need that content have been changed just before displaying, not before saving in DB.

Comment: Well, `before page is uploaded` it's not the same as `before the content is displayed`, for that just change the filter hook to `the_content` samples here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content